# Powershell DirectoryService object error neither caught nor trapped

Tags: powershell, error-handling, active-directory

This is part of my script:

```
Trap {Write-Output 'Authentication Error trapped'}
Try {New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry $strDistinguishedName,$strUsername,$strPlainPassword -ErrorAction stop}
Catch{Write-Output 'Authentication Error catched'}
Write-Output 'Script has not trapped nor catched the error but continued'
```

The error is just terminating the script and I found no way to catch or trap the error.

The script does even not write the last line which means it has completely exited the script.

Here is the whole output:

```
PS C:\Temp> & .\test.ps1
format-default : The following exception occurred while retrieving member "distinguishedName": "Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.
"+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [format-default], ExtendedTypeSystemException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CatchFromBaseGetMember,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.FormatDefaultCommand
PS C:\Temp>
```

The error type is:

```
PS C:\Temp> $Error[0].GetType()
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                                                                             
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                                                             
True     True     CmdletInvocationException                System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException                                                                                                                        
PS C:\Temp>
```

I tried :

- Catch or Trap [System.Exception]
- Catch or Trap [System.Management]
- to remove the -ErrorAction parameter
- to use the $ErrorActionPreference variable

Does anybody know how to trap this error?

Comment: That is strange, the exception actually comes from `format-default` which is the output formatter for showing things in the console, like piping to `Out-Default`. The `New-Object` call is not failing, and you can see that by writing `$x = try { new-object ... } catch { }` and there's no error. But if you then try to `$x` to see what it is, there's an error. After that, try `"$x"` and it claims to be a `System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry`. But you can't `$x.GetType()` because it throws `ParentContainsErrorRecordException`. What is going on there?

Comment: Same thing discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26262384/478656

Comment: You are right for the link.
I searched but didn't find a topic already talking about this strange behaviour. Your query was more effecient than mine ;-)
You can publish your link as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently come up against the same error, trying to instantiate a DirectoryEntry object to RootDSE on a domain where there is no trust with the current domain.
What I found is that calling a method on the resulting object allows the exception to be successfully trapped/caught.

So this doesn't work as might be expected:

```
try 
{
    $RDSE = [adsi]"LDAP://UntrustedService/RootDSE"
}
catch
{
    Write-Warning "Unable to connect to service"
}
```

But this does:

```
try 
{
    $RDSE=[adsi]"LDAP://UntrustedService/RootDSE"
    [void]$RDSE.ToString()
}
catch [System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException]
{
    Write-Warning "Unable to connect to service"
}
catch #Default
{
    Write-Warning "Some other error"
}
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion.
However I cannot use your object because I need the **ValidateCredentials** method in my case.
Maybe it can help somebody else reading this post... :-)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error and the comment from @TessellatingHeckler helped me.
Piping the result to `Out-Null` fixed it for me. So you can try the following:

```
Trap {Write-Output 'Authentication Error trapped'}
Try {New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry $strDistinguishedName,$strUsername,$strPlainPassword -ErrorAction stop | Out-Null}
Catch{Write-Output 'Authentication Error catched'}
Write-Output 'Script has not trapped nor catched the error but continued'
```